# Why I am not able to load excel files generated in the morning, but can load them in the afternoon in Python using Openpyxl

Tags: python

I am using Python Openpyxl to import excel files which are generated by a online tool. When I import the files generated in the morning, I got an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 8, in <module>
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook (temp2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 201, in load_workbook
wb.properties = DocumentProperties.from_tree(src)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 89, in from_tree
return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\core.py", line 106, in__init__
self.modified = modified
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 267, in __set__
value = W3CDTF_to_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\datetime.py", line 40, in W3CDTF_to_datetime
dt = [int(v) for v in match.groups()[:6]]
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

The strange thing is I only got this error when I importing the files which are generated by the online tool in the morning. I tried the same file but generated in the afternoon, it works very well. I'm confused where the problem is. There are no fields in the excel files related to time. And the files generated in the morning and in the afternoon are exactly the same except the modified time. Does anybody can help me with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Excel files created from this online tool isn't well compatible with openpyxl**

The function `load_workbook` will get workbook-level information and assign to Workbook()'s `wb.properties` from 'docProps/core.xml' by opening excel file through `zipfile`. One piece of information is modified time.

The value of modified raise the error, it can't be transported into `datetime`. The pattern of 'modified' must be `openpyxl.utils.datetime.W3CDTF_REGEX`, which is [W3CDTF|W3C Date and Time Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

You can check the excel's modified time if it corresponds to W3CDTF. Here is the code:

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import _validate_archive
archive = _validate_archive('/path/to/yourexcel.xlsx')
valid_files = archive.namelist()

# you'll find 'xx/core.xml' I'm not sure if it's 'docProps/core.xml'
print valid_files

# read 'xx/core.xml'
wb_info = archive.read('docProps/core.xml')
print wb_info
```

In *wb_info*, you will find something like

`<dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2017-04-01T22:48:48Z</dcterms:modified>`.

Contrast *wb_info* of excel files from online tool and your pc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's really helpful!